# Synchronization and ServletContextListener

Tags: java, synchronization, servletcontextlistener

Do I need to perform synchronization while accessing the application scope in a ServletContextListener? Can you explain, and provide code that demonstrates this?

Comment: The question lacks context. Can you explain, and provide code that demonstrates your question?

Comment: There is nothing to show. Strictly theoretical question.

Comment: What do you mean by "application scope"?